# Android local auth using keystore

Tags: java, encryption

I'm performing encryption using an Android secret with flags set like this:

```
.setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(true)
                .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(-1)
```

However, I'm getting the following exception:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
   Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Key user not authenticated
```

Given the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String originalData = "Your sensitive information here";
    public static final String SHARED_PREFS_NAME = "MySharedPreferences";
    public static final String ENCRYPTED_DATA_KEY = "encrypted_data";
    public static final String ENCRYPTED_DECRYPTED_IV = "encrypt_decrypt_IV";
    public static final String DECRYPTED_DATA_KEY = "decrypted_data";


    private static final String ANDROID_KEY_STORE = "AndroidKeyStore";


    private static final String KEY_ALIAS = "key009";

    private  Context context;

    private BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt;
    private BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo biometricPromptInfo;
    boolean isEncrypt;
    Button btnGetKey, btnBioMetricRegister, biometricLoginButton, btnDecrypt;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.encrypt_decrypt_layout);
        context = MainActivity.this;

        btnGetKey = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGetKey);
        btnBioMetricRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBioMetricRegister);
        biometricLoginButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.biometricLoginButton);
        btnDecrypt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDecrypt);

        btnGetKey.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                generateKey();
            }
        });


        btnBioMetricRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                isEncrypt = true;
                BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject cryptoObject = getCrypto();

                if (cryptoObject != null) {

                    biometricPrompt.authenticate(biometricPromptInfo, cryptoObject);
                } else {
                    // Key is invalidated - this is never triggered
                   Log.d("Error", "Key is invalidated - this is never triggered");
                }
            }
        });

        biometricLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                isEncrypt = false;
                BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject cryptoObject = getCrypto();

                if (cryptoObject != null) {

                    biometricPrompt.authenticate(biometricPromptInfo,  cryptoObject);
                } else {
                   // Key is invalidated - this is never triggered
                    Log.d("Error", "Key is invalidated - this is never triggered");
                }
            }
        });


        btnDecrypt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              //  isEncrypt = false;
              //  decryptSavedString();
            }
        });
        // Set up prompt
        biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt(
                this,
                ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
                new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                    // no-op

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode, @NonNull CharSequence errString) {
                        super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);

                    }

                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(@NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
                        super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);

                        if(isEncrypt) {
                            // Encrypt the data
                           encryptAndSaveString(originalData);
                          //  Log.d("encrypted Data", encryptedData);
                        }else{

                            String  strDecryptedData = decryptSavedString();

                        // Use the decrypted data as needed
                            Log.d("Decrypted Data @@@", strDecryptedData!=null?strDecryptedData:"Error");
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
                        super.onAuthenticationFailed();
                    }
                }
        );

        // Prompt info
        biometricPromptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                .setTitle("Title")
                .setNegativeButtonText("Test")
                //.setAllowedAuthenticators(BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG)
                .build();

     
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private void generateKey() {
        try {
            KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
            keyGenerator.init(getKeyGen());
            keyGenerator.generateKey();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Cipher getCipher() throws Exception {
        return Cipher.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/"
                        + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                        + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7
        );
    }

    private SecretKey getKey() throws Exception {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
        keyStore.load(null);
        return (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_ALIAS, null);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private KeyGenParameterSpec getKeyGen() {
        return new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                KEY_ALIAS,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
        ).setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(true)
                .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(-1)
                .build();
    }
   


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    public void encryptAndSaveString(String dataToEncrypt) {
        try {
            SecretKey secretKey = getKey();
            if (secretKey != null) {
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/"
                        + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                        + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);

                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

                byte[] iv = cipher.getIV();
                byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(dataToEncrypt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                saveIVToPrefs(Base64.encodeToString(iv, Base64.DEFAULT));
                saveEncryptedDataToPrefs(Base64.encodeToString(iv, Base64.DEFAULT),
                        Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT));
                Log.d("encrypted Data@@@", getEncryptedDataFromPrefs(ENCRYPTED_DATA_KEY + "_data"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if(e instanceof KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException | e instanceof InvalidKeyException){
                Log.e("InvalidKeyException ", "@Encrypt...");
                try {
                    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
                    keyStore.load(null);
                    keyStore.deleteEntry(KEY_ALIAS);
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
                         IOException | java.security.KeyStoreException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (java.security.cert.CertificateException ex) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    public String decryptSavedString() {
        try {

            SecretKey secretKey = getKey();
            if (secretKey != null) {
                String ivString1= getEncryptedDataFromPrefs(ENCRYPTED_DATA_KEY + "_iv");
                String encryptedDataString = getEncryptedDataFromPrefs(ENCRYPTED_DATA_KEY + "_data");
          //  String ivString = getIVToPrefs();
                if (ivString1 != null && encryptedDataString != null) {
                    byte[] iv1 = Base64.decode(ivString1, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    //byte[] iv = Base64.decode(ivString, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    byte[] encryptedData = Base64.decode(encryptedDataString, Base64.DEFAULT);

                    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/"
                            + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                            + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);

                    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv1));

                    byte[] decryptedBytes = new byte[0];
                    try {
                        decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);
                    } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                    }
                    String decryptedData = new String(decryptedBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    saveDecryptedDataToPrefs(decryptedData);
                    return decryptedData;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if(e instanceof KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException | e instanceof InvalidKeyException){
                Log.e("InvalidKeyException ", "@Decrypt...");

            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


  
    private void saveEncryptedDataToPrefs(String iv, String data) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString(ENCRYPTED_DATA_KEY + "_iv", iv);
        editor.putString(ENCRYPTED_DATA_KEY + "_data", data);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public String getEncryptedDataFromPrefs(String key) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getString(key, null);
    }

    private void saveDecryptedDataToPrefs(String data) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString(DECRYPTED_DATA_KEY, data);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public String getDecryptedDataFromPrefs() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getString(DECRYPTED_DATA_KEY, null);
    }

    private void saveIVToPrefs(String data) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString(ENCRYPTED_DECRYPTED_IV, data);
        editor.apply();
    }
    private String getIVToPrefs() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getString(ENCRYPTED_DECRYPTED_IV, "");

    }


}
```

I want to encrypt / decrypt using secret key but if user add/remove fingerprint it will throw `KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException`

Comment: There may be a great question hidden inside this post, but given the very bad formatting and hard to understand context when this error occurs it is hard to answer it or vote it up.  I'm presuming you get this exception when calling   `cipher.doFinal` during encryption?

Comment: yes, you are right. Duruning encryption on cipher.doFinal I get above mentioned exception.